# Why the html layout disordered when I use Ajax and Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, json, django, django-templates

I use django to develop a blog and I add a endless load feature to display all article in homepage,but here are some problems.

in my views.py,I write this code:

```
...
json_list = []
for post in posts:
    t = get_template('blog/ajax_post.html')
    html = t.render(Context({'post': post}))
    json_list.append({
        'html': html,
    })
data = json.dumps(json_list)
return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

the template 'blog/ajax_post.html' like this:

```
<div class="col s10 m10">
<a href={% url 'blog:detail' post.id %}><span class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</span></a>
</div>
<a class="right waves-effect waves-light btn" href={% url 'blog:detail' post.id %}>read more</a>
```

when I render in views,the render is good.For example,I print the html content:

```
<a href='post/6'><span class="card-title">test title</span></a>
<a class="right waves-effect waves-light btn" href='post/6'>read more</a>
```

but when it be delivered to front use json(return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")),the layout was disordered.I print them,the output like this:

```
<a href='post/6'></a><span class="card-title">test title</span>(notice here)
<a class="right waves-effect waves-light btn" href='post/6'></a>read more(notice here)
```

the 'span' tag or 'read more' is out of the 'a' tag.Why this?

ps:My english is a little poor.I hope you can understand what I say and give me some help.Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you everybody,I got a solution in another place.The solution is:Don't forgot to add " " to you url template tags,like this: href="{% url 'blog:detail' post.id %}",not href={% url 'blog:detail' post.id %}.